# A question related to a convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be $f\in C([0,\infty ])$, such that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L $.

Calculate

$$ \int _{0}^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx $$

Help?

Comment: Are you looking for the improper Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from @Sami Ben Romdhane is incomplete since it contains 
$$ \int_1^2\frac{f(x)}{x}dx. $$
Here is the complete answer.

Let $0<A<2A<B$ and define
\begin{eqnarray*}
 g(A,B)&=&\int_A^B\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx=\int_A^B\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_A^B\frac{f(2x)}{x}dx\\
&=&\int_A^B\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_{2A}^{2B}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx\\
&=&\int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_{B}^{2B}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then by the Integral Mean Value Theorem in $[A, 2A]$ and $[B, 2B]$, we have
$$ \int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=f(c_1)\int_A^{2A}\frac{1}{x}dx=f(c_1)\ln 2, \int_B^{2B}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=f(c_2)\int_B^{2B}\frac{1}{x}dx=f(c_2)\ln 2 $$
where $A<c_1<2A, B<c_2<2B$. Thus
$$ g(A,B)=(f(c_1)-f(c_2))\ln2. $$
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx&=&\lim_{A\to 0^+,B\to\infty}g(A,B)\\
&=&\lim_{A\to 0^+,B\to\infty}(f(c_1)-f(c_2))\ln2\\
&=&(f(0)-L)\ln 2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 11):

By an obvious change variable we have

$$\int_1^A\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx=\int_1^A\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_2^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_1^2\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$

Now since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ we prove easily that
$$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=L\log2\tag{*}$$
so
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx=\int_1^2\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-L\log2$$

**Edit** Here I explain the equality $(*)$:

We have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ so for $\epsilon>0$ there's $A>0$ and if $x\ge A$ we have $|f(x)-L|\le\epsilon$, hence
$$\left|\int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-L\log2\right|=\left|\int_A^{2A}\frac{f(x)-L}{x}dx\right|\le\int_A^{2A}\frac{|f(x)-L|}{x}dx\le\epsilon\log2$$
so we have the desired equality.

Comment: I missed the upper limits, I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: the lower bound is from 0... sorry for the mistake... does that change anything? and another thing, is it ok to split an infanant integral like that?

Comment: @Tomer Repeat the same method but write $$\int_\epsilon^A=\cdots$$ and finaly pass to the limit $\epsilon\to0$ and $A\to\infty$

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at the limit $L \log 2$?

Comment: @Alex I'll edit my answer and explain why.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: ok thanks

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer.

Comment: Is it a continuous verision of this property: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323258/cauchy-problem-real-analysis ?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, your answer is incomplete. Please see the answer below.

Comment: @xpaul The answer is not incomplete since the question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Condition $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ is not enough. To see that the problem is underdetermined, take $f(x)=L+\frac{C}{1+x}$ with any prescribed constant $C$.
For such $f$, the improper integral 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx=C\cdot\ln{2}$$
with an arbitrary given $C$ while $f(\infty)=L$. Combining this with the answer from *@xpaul*, we get a correct formulation of the OP problem: *Given the values* $f(0)$ *and* $f(\infty)$ *of some function* $f\in C[0,\infty]$, *calculate the improper integral*
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx$$
*when it does converge*.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.