# Given f(x), a continous function on R such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L$, what is $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm sure I'm missing something. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646453/a-question-related-to-a-convergence-of-an-integral).

Comment: Thanks for this.